# Image Compression using imfinfo function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-compression

I am trying to calculate the compression ratio of a given image. My matlab code is as follows:

temp = imfinfo('flowers.jpg');
comperssion_ratio = (temp.Width * temp.Height * temp.BitDepth) / temp.FileSize;

The imfinfo displays the following:

```
       FileSize: 11569
         Format: 'jpg'
  FormatVersion: ''
          Width: 430
         Height: 430
       BitDepth: 8
      ColorType: 'grayscale'
FormatSignature: ''
NumberOfSamples: 1
   CodingMethod: 'Huffman'
  CodingProcess: 'Sequential'
        Comment: {}
```

Running the above code gives me a compression ratio of about 120 which is huge and does not seem right. Is there something that I'm doing wrong? I went through a document from MIT and they showed that the Width and Height and BitDepth should be divided by 8 and then divided by the FileSize. Why divide by 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The division by factor of 8 is to convert bits to bytes.

According to the [Matlab documentation for imfinfo](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imfinfo.html)

the FileSize parameter is the size of the compressed file, in bytes.

The compression ratio is defined as:

> uncompressed size of image in bytes/compressed size of file in bytes

***imfinfo*** gives you the pixel width, height, and bits per pixel (bit depth). From that you can compute the uncompressed size in bits, and divide by 8 to get bytes.

For the uncompressed image , you have 430*430*8/8 = 184,900 bytes.

The size of the compressed image is 11569 bytes.

So the compression ratio is actually 184,900/11569 or 15.98, not an unreasonable value for JPEG.